# TestFlight AIR Native Extension

Tags: ios, air, testflight

I'm likely doing something dumb here but I'm wondering if someone can point out what exactly it is.

I'm attempting to include the TestFlight ANE in my project with the following code...

```
<extensions>
    <extensionID>com.adobe.ane.testFlight</extensionID>
</extensions>
```

This works fine for other Gaming SDK 1.2 ANE's such as gameCenter and stageAd however when I attempt to use TestFlight I receive the following error.

"An implementation for native extension 'com.adobe.ane.testFlight' required by the application was not found for the target platform."

This doesn't work for either Android or iOS so there is clearly something wrong with the way I'm linking the extension.

Comment: Have to add this as a comment for now...

The correct code is below.

`<extensionID>com.adobe.ane.TestFlightImpl</extensionID>`

Comment: Thanks! link to the latest ANE: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1153054